# How to return uknown data-types from the same function? (Golang)

Tags: go, return-type

I'm a little new to Golang and one thing that'd I find very useful is if I could return unknown value types to a function.

Is there a way to return unknown different types of values in the same function using Golang?

Comment: Return an `interface{}` and use type assertions to access the underlying value

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Types switches are described in the language specification. See https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    p := BasedOnType(true)
    fmt.Println(p) //map[bool:true]
    p = BasedOnType(2)
    fmt.Println(p) //map[]
}

func BasedOnType(i interface{}) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
    switch x := i.(type) {
    case bool, float64, string:
        k := fmt.Sprintf("%T", x)
        v := fmt.Sprintf("%v", x)
        m[k] = v
        return m
    default:
        return m
    }
}
```

For The Go Playground see https://play.golang.org/p/0ahpua7ujb2.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a pattern like this. I made a generic **Result** type which stores **Data** which is an **interface** and **Err** which is an **error** type. So I can reuse the Result type to return a different type of a different function. Then use [switch type](https://tour.golang.org/methods/16) to determine what type the function returns.
The Go Playground please check https://play.golang.org/p/SbwGOP_aXLG

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "errors"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    what := "multiple"
    result := Func(what)
    if result.Err != nil {
        fmt.Println(result.Err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    
    switch res := result.Data.(type) {
        case Gopher:
            fmt.Println("Gopher name : ", res.Name)
        case Gophers:
            for _, g := range res {
                fmt.Println("Gopher name : ", g.Name)
            }
    }
}

type Result struct {
    Data interface{}
    Err error
}

type Gopher struct {
    Name string
}

type Gophers []Gopher

func Func(what string) Result {
    switch what {
        case "one":
            return Result{Data: Gopher{"gopher one"}}
        
        case "multiple":
            return Result{Data: Gophers{Gopher{"gopher one"}, Gopher{"gopher two"}}}
        
        
    }
    return Result{Err: errors.New("invalid what")}
}
```